# Migrating EC2 SQL Server to HyperV On Premise

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2

I'm wondering if any of you have migrated SQL servers from EC2 to on-premise? I'm toying with doing backup and restore on new onprem server, however the file copy test took over 24 hours. Given that I've got a weekend to do this move/build I'm wondering if doing something like building a replication of the EC2 to an on-prem server would be a better idea.

Comment: Or take a FULL backup ahead of time and restore it with `NORECOVERY`, then at cutover time, just take a DIFF backup and restore it to the new server.  Mirroring way would work here also, but several factors like DB size and throughput could impact the server that is currently up and operational now.